# How to change background color of readonly textbox in css

Tags: html, css

How to change background color of readonly textbox in css

Comment: what do you mean by "readonly textbox"?

Comment: If you want a proper answer, you should post a proper question. What's your current code ? What triggers the change ? Are you using any JS library (like jQuery, for example) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are too many unkowns in your question. Which browser do you want support? If you say textbox you seem to use ASP.NET, but there is no tag at you question.

Generally said, the behaviour between the browsers are different.

Consider the following html

> ```
> <html>
>       <head>
>       </head>
>       <body>
>              <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="This is a test" style="background-color:Black; color:Lime;" />
>       </body>
> </html>
> ```

IE8 renders the background color properly, but disabled controls will always have gray text with shadows. Mozille Firefox beside that renders the control correct and i am sure there will be difference all over the different browsers and even between the browser versions (IE6 would interprete the color values correctly too).

If you want to have a html regardless which browser you use, you have to use a span or other inline element, to format it with border and colors you want, instead of using a input element.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. is there possible way I can use that as external CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
input[disabled="disabled"] { background:url("url-to-background-image.jpg") no-repeat #fff; }
```

and for older browser that doesnt support this selector, you can use jQuery to apply a class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[disabled="disabled"]").addClass('disabled');
});
```

And unless it's disabled all the time, you should provide js for removing the class along with js for enabling it.

Comment: yes just change the jquery css selector to :  $("input[readonly="readonly"]")

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
input:-moz-read-only { /* For Firefox */
    background-color: yellow;
}

input:read-only {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi This will surely work for your code. Just try this..

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
         <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="JavaScript is the best" style="background-color:Black; color:green;" />
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi, this is the code from the accepted answer, without all other explaination. Please try to don't duplicate answer, prefer upvote others

Comment: Oh Sorry, by the way I have not copied anything. I have written the full code by myself, but I cant also upvote has I still dont have 15 repotations

Comment: Oh yes, it's 15 and not 5. And sorry but it's seems very similar to accepted answer

Answer (score -2):

You can change the background color in css using this code but before that make sure your html page is linked with your css page.

```
Body {
      Background-color: red;

     }
```

Hope this code will work for you.

Comment: Please note the question title is **"How to change background color of readonly textbox in css"**.